# Dibujar esquina con curva interna en css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bien, estoy intentando hacer algo que quizas sea un poco complicado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ser mas especificos intento hacer esta figura... PERO, necesito que sea sin :after o :before porque necesito que sea el pseudo elemento :before quien tome esta forma.
Se supone que con el `border-radius` haces un circulo pero como hago esta figura?

Pdta: necesito que la parte de la curva, osea donde iria el circulo, sea transparente, no puedo poner un circulo de color solido ahi, necesito que sea transparente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

esta es una opción.

```css
#b1 {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
      
}
#b2 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;  
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="b1">
  <div id="b2">
</div>
</div>
```

y esta esta otra opción:

```css
div {
  background: tan;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: -90px -100px 0px 0px black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  // outline: .65em solid #655;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  border-right: 87px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 87px solid transparent;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-left: -7px;
 }
```

```html
<div/>
```

y la opción para los que no tienen mucha experiencia:
una imagen:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3wdY.png')
              no-repeat, linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
  background-position: 10px 10px, 0px;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

```html
<div/>
```

Comment: Se ve genial, pero necesito que la parte del circulo sea transparente, no blanca o de algun color solido. Solo transparente

Comment: edite la respuesta ara adecuarla a tus necesidades